# Compare MVVM WPF and MVC/MVVM AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, mvvm, mvw

**MVVM Architure in WPF seems to be understandable.**

1. The model in the MVVM pattern encapsulates business logic and
   data.(**It is a specific class who in charge of the business login
   and data**)
2. The view's responsibility is to define the structure and appearance
   of what the user sees on the screen. (**implements by having a XAML
   page**)
3. The view model in the MVVM pattern encapsulates the presentation
   logic and data for the view.(**It is a specific class who in charge
   of the presention login**)

**Now lets compare it to Angularjs Design pattern MVC/MVVM.**

4. The view is the DOM(html).
5. The ViewModel is:

> the **$scope** object could be considered the **ViewModel** that is being
>   decorated by a function that we call a **Controller.**

**And Here Comes The Question**

What is the Model in this AngularJS design pattern ?

I understood that maybe the Services should be the model ? can someone make it clear to me?

**BTW i want to use ES6 Class to be the model as we talked about in the MVVM WPF Design pattern where the model is a Class**.

Comment: Is Angular that much different than Knockout? Because, in Knockoutjs, you define a javascript object that's your ViewModel, which has observable properties and collections, and you apply it to your UI via the javascript command `ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);`  Maybe knockout is better suited to your understanding of the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

The models can come from services or factories, e.g.:

```
angular.module("myModule")
       .factory("urlFactory", function() {
           return {
               myModelSource: 'http://localhost:38324/api/myModel'
           }
       })
       .service("dataSource", ["$http", "urlFactory", function($http, urlFactory) {
           return {
               getMyModel: function() {
                   return $http.get(urlFactory.myModelSource);
               }
           }
       }])
       .controller("myController", ["$scope", "dataSource", function($scope, dataSource) {
           dataSource.getMyModel().then(function(myModel) {
               $scope.viewModel = myModel;
           });
       }]);
```

Comment: another question that come with this answer is can i using variables in this section i mean factory , services, providers etc... and does this vars are singletone i mean if i change the info it will stay till the application still alive?

Comment: You can make them whatever you want.  In fact, under the hood there is no real difference between a factory and a service.  It's just a dependency-injected object.